# RegEx simple parser of css selectors

Tags: css, regex

I want to add scope to my selectors.
A good way to achieve it in my opinion is to select css selector and return mySelector + oldSelector

For example I have `.old { background: black; }`, I would transform it into `.mySelector .old { background: black; }`

Let's say I have this CSS

```
.a
{
background: red;
}
#b {
background: green;
}
input {
background: blue;
}
[type=custom] {
background: white;
}
```

I would do `.+?{`, but it selects not needed parts. Inverse of `{.+?}` would work, but I don't know how to inverse it. Any ideas ?

Comment: F.e. for `.foo, .bar { … }` I’d expect you would want to add `.mySelector` before _both_? // This might be more complex than you think – I’d suggest you look for a library that has implemented CSS rule parsing already.

Comment: Do not parse CSS with regexps. It's brittle and unreliable. Regexps are for string manipulation, not parsing of languages (other than the very simplest kind). There are many threads here on SO on this topic. Search for them. If you must manipulate CSS sheets and rules, do so using the APIs available for that purpose, starting with `document.styleSheets` etc.

Comment: @CBroe that's rigth, to both. This very simple rule `{.+?}` almost achieves it and selects everything after selectors. I only need to inverse it. Isn't it possible ?


@torazaburo I think it's the case of simplest kind. I need to inverse regex of 5 chars ( `{.+?}` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I can use `String.match({.+?})` to get all rules and `String.split({.+?})` to get selectors **in JavaScript**.

Also I've found a library to easily parse CSS in JavaScript https://github.com/reworkcss/css